# How are we able to know a IO is blocking or non-blocking

Tags: c#

Reading C# documentation, I wonder how one can know if the IO is blocking or not. For example the BinaryWriter.Write method, I cannot find any information on the documentation on whether the method is blocking.

Comment: I think one safe rule of thumb is to assume methods are synchronous unless the docs explicitly state they are async. Another pattern the framework uses is to suffix async methods with "Async", or provide BeginXXX/EndXXX method pairs.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`BinaryWriter.Write` only returns when its work is completed. That makes it blocking. The waiting time is potentially unbounded.

Asynchronous methods are usually easy to spot because they return `Task` or `IAsyncResult` (which corresponds to the old APM pattern). They also are named appropriately (`BeginXxx` or `XxxAsync`). When such a method returns you do not have the result yet. That indicates to you that the computation is still unfinished.

The docs call this property out for async methods. Because almost all methods are blocking and synchronous (e.g. all string methods) this behavior not noted in the docs. It is the default.

Answer (score 1):

Since it does not provide `BeginWrite` and its corresponding `EndWrite` methods, it has to be blocking.